# How to use Docker BuildKit extensions in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I'm trying to do something a bit slick, and of course running into issues.

Specifically, I am using a Docker-based environment build system ([Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/)).  I'm feeding it a Dockerfile that it then builds a cluster around, using docker-compose.  Locally, this works fine.  I also have it working great inside a GitHub Action to spin up a local-dev-identical environment for testing.  Quite nice.

However, now I'm trying to expand the Dockerfile using the [Dockerfile Plus](https://github.com/edrevo/dockerfile-plus) extension.  My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus

INCLUDE+ ./docker/prod/Dockerfile

COPY docker/dev/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-docker-custom.ini

# Other stuff here.
```

This works great for me locally, and I get the contents of `docker/prod/Dockerfile` included into my docker build.

When I run the same configuration inside a GitHub Actions workflow, I get a syntax error on the `INCLUDE+` line, indicating that the extension is not being loaded.  It uses BuildKit (according to the project page), which should be enabled by default on any recent Docker version, it says.  Yet whatever is on GitHub is not using BuildKit.  I've tried enabling it by setting the env vars explicitly (as specified on the Dockerfile+ project page), but it still doesn't seem to work.

How can I get Dockerfile+ working in GitHub Actions?  Of note, I do not run the `docker build` command myself (it's run by docker-compose, using files generated on the fly by Lando), so I cannot modify that specific command.  But I didn't need to locally anyway, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action ?

Comment: I have.  It does not seem to have any effect. Something in how Lando is calling docker-compose must be bypassing buildx.

Comment: Can you provide minimal github repo where you can show you dockerfile and workflow code?